# Which stock photo site for industrial / maritime / communications images?

Tags: stock-photography

I am on a very limited budget (small start-up with little funding), and would like some stock images, whether photos or line-drawings, for a website and some brochures.

In addition to the standard "man with glasses starting intently at computer screen who's contents he does not understand" and such-like business images, I need images in several fields:

- oil & gas (refineries, rigs, etc)
- industrial-maritime (freight liners and the like)
- "measurement" which is sort of a vague concept, sorry
- "communication" which is another. Latops/PCs communicating via WiFi, public 'phone network or satellite with a database

Some of these are definite objects (large ship) and some are concept (network).

Can someone recommend a good stock photo site for me? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a few good micro-stock sites I can recommend. I'm almost certain each site will have what you are looking for, at affordable prices.

- [Bigstockphoto](http://www.bigstockphoto.com/)
- [Fotolia](http://us.fotolia.com/)
- [Dreamstime](http://www.dreamstime.com/)
- [Shutterstock](http://www.shutterstock.com/)

Answer (score 3):

It's well worth [searching](http://www.flickr.com/search/?q=Ship&l=comm&ss=2&ct=0&mt=photos&adv=1&s=int) the Creative Commons licensed images on Flickr, I found a number of very strong images for a port website I recently designed (on a minimal budget).

Answer (score 1):

Check out this collection of [Science and Technology pictures](http://cutcaster.com/browse/Science-and-Technology/2381-General/) that cover your topics needed.

Hope those help and please let me know what other image needs you have.